# Jquery val() always grabs first select value no matter which is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery to allow users to upload an image via Ajax in a form (the image uploads before the form is actually submitted). I've added the ability to add a watermark to each image that is uploaded (this is done in upload_image.php) this part works fine.

The user can select where they want the watermark to be placed on their image via a form select. I'm using Jquery's .val() to grab the value of the id="watermark" select and add it as a query string value to be passed to upload_image.php.

The problem is that it always passes the first select value no matter what I actually select in the form. I tried putting it in a function (thought it was grabbing the value on page load) no luck there. I changed the select to radio buttons. It still grabs the value of the first radio button on the page; no matter what you select.

Here is the portion of the script that handles this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){

    // build URL to php upload script with watermark placement
    function setWatermark() {
        var uploadUrl = 'http://www.mysite.com/upload_image.php?w=';
        var watermarkValue = $('#watermark').val();
        var watermarkUrl = uploadUrl + watermarkValue;
        return watermarkUrl;
    }

    var btnUpload=$('#upload');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: setWatermark(),
        name: 'uploadfile',
    });

});
</script>
```

This is the form (with irrelevant fields removed):

```
<form id="image_form" action="this_form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select id="watermark">
        <option value="top_left">Top Left</option>
        <option value="top_right">Top Right</option>
        <option value="center">Center</option>
        <option value="bottom_left">Bottom Left</option>
        <option value="bottom_right">Bottom Right</option>
    </select>
    <div id="upload" ><span><img src="upload_button.jpg" /></span></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To execute this code:

```
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
    action: setWatermark(),
    name: 'uploadfile',
});
```

The browser must first construct the arguments to pass to the constructor. To construct the second argument, the object, it must call `setWatermark` to get the value for the `action` property. This is where your problem is; `setWatermark` is being called when the `AjaxUpload` object is created.

I don't know what `AjaxUpload` is, but you'll have to find a way to get it to call a function when it needs the `action` rather than it being provided as a constant in the options.